# iptables forwarding ignored

Tags: iptables, routing, forwarding

I'm having an issue forwarding traffic from one interface to another. It seems my forwarding rules are not being respected.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Here's how my IPtable looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 8184 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             LOG level warning
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 82 packets, 11632 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I want anything coming from 192.168.0.0/24 to be forwarded to interface tun0. And I want the forwarded traffic to logged.

Now If I go ahead and tun the following command:

```
ping 10.8.0.2
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1974 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1069 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=669 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=670 ms
```

However, if I do :

```
ping 10.8.0.2 -I eth0
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2) from 192.168.0.10 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Traffic is not being forwarded. Any ideas why? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dadriel makes an excellent point about traffic originating locally not passing through the `FORWARD` chain, but you have a more fundamental problem: this is not how `iptables` rules work. They don't decide *how* a packet should be forwarded (at least not easily), they decide *whether* it should be forwarded.  Your rules above log and permit any `NEW` traffic that comes from `192.168.0.0/24` and is leaving via `tun0`, but they don't force traffic that fits the former criteria to take the latter route.

The **routing tables** decide how traffic will be forwarded, and it sounds like you want **policy-based routing** (ie, the choice about how to route to be based on something other than the destination IP address - in your case, the source IP address).

You should look into [`iproute2`](http://lartc.org/howto/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can't test forwarding like this, since the packets originating from the server you are using as forwarder never traverse that chain.

But the real issue here is that you are only forwarding NEW connections, which is wrong. This will cause the statement only to work for the first time your server sees the connection. Everything after that is not forwarded anymore.

Comment: Forwarding --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED  does not solve the issue.